# Get path to all XML's nodes

Tags: java, xml

I have an example XML as follows:

```
<message>
  <metadata> 
    <msg_id>1</msg_id>
    <client_type>type1</client_type>
  </metadata>
  <individual>
    <name>John</name>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
      <additional_information>
        <e_mail>aaa@gmail.com</e_mail>
        <phone_number>11110000</phone_number>
      </additional_information>
  </individual>
</message>
```

my goal is to get output which will show me the path to every element XML like here:

```
/message/metadata/msg_id
/message/metadata/client_type
/message/individual/name
```

and so one. How can I handle this in Java?

Thanks a lot in advance for any hints!

Comment: What have you tried this far? Consider posting your code. Having shown some effort in terms of actual code is usually considered a good practice when asking questions. It's also much easier to provide a usable answer after having seen what you've already tried.

Comment: Hello JMK, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @vanje imho I know how to ask good question here. But how can I show what I have already done when I am stucked and have no idea where to start? :)

Comment: Then do some research. As a starting point, you should consider using a SAX parser. Google for it. There you can implement a callback for each start and end element. You could hold a stack for the element path. Adding the current element at start element and removing the last element on end element callback.

Comment: If you have no idea where to start, type "parse XML with Java" into Google.  Now you have a place to start research from.  (Also, the official Java Tutorials have a decent trail on XML processing.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can you [xPath](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/) to select nodes by expressions and print the path of each nodes,

Here is the java code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("src/main/resources/file.xml");
    XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "//*[not(*)]";

    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(file);
    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(getXPath(nodeList.item(i)));
    }
}

private static String getXPath(Node node) {
    Node parent = node.getParentNode();
    if (parent == null) {
        return node.getNodeName();
    }
    return getXPath(parent) + "/" + node.getNodeName();
}
```

The final output is :

document/message/metadata/msg_id

document/message/metadata/client_type

document/message/individual/name

document/message/individual/surname

Comment: I was trying to figure out everything like in the following example, but when I changed one variable String expression = "/Employees/Employee/firstname" to String expression = "/Employees" ; then nodeList returned only with one value. My goal is goal is clearly described in the question. Can you help me how to recreate this example?

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! This is what I have been looking for. I have one additional question to your solution. What if I would like to have all the nodes in this pattern after "message/metadata" in my example? So the result will be only /message/metadata/msg_id and /message/metadata/client_type without all the rest?

Comment: change the string expression with String expression = "/message/metadata/*[not(*)]";

Comment: I have found a problem with your solution. If I have more complex XML to read and I want to start from particular node only first children are shown. Please take a look on my edited question to see that if I want to get only information from message/individual/ node the output is only /message/individual/name and /message/individual/surname without /additional_information/ node values.

Comment: @JMK you should try with this : String expression = "/message/individual//*[not(*)]";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107204/discussion-between-jmk-and-oliv37).

Answer (score 6):

Can't comment yet (no points yet), but the previously supplied answer doesn't address Nodes inside an array. the following will determine the full Path to a node when the child node being checked is inside an array element of some sort

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   File file = new File("src/main/resources/file.xml");
   XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
   String expression = "//*[not(*)]";

   DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = 
   DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document document = builder.parse(file);
   document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

   NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) 
   xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
      System.out.println(getNodePath(nodeList.item(i)));
   }
}

/**
 * Builds the Path to the Node in the XML Structure.
 *
 * @param node Child {@link Node}
 * @return {@link String} representation of Path to XML Node.
 */
public String getNodePath(Node node) {
    if(node == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node cannot be null");
    }
    StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder("/");
    pathBuilder.append(node.getNodeName());

    Node currentNode = node;

    if(currentNode.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
        while (currentNode.getParentNode() != null) {
            currentNode = currentNode.getParentNode();

            if(currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
                break;
            } else if(getIndexOfArrayNode(currentNode) != null) {
                pathBuilder.insert(0, "/" + currentNode.getNodeName() + "[" + getIndexOfArrayNode(currentNode) + "]");
            } else {
                pathBuilder.insert(0, "/" + currentNode.getNodeName());
            }
        }
    }

    return pathBuilder.toString();
}

/**
 * TODO - doesn't handle Formatted XML - treats formatting as Text Nodes and needs to skip these.
 *
 * Light node test to see if Node is part of an Array of Elements.
 *
 * @param node {@link Node}
 * @return True if part of an array. Otherwise false.
 */
private boolean isArrayNode(Node node) {
    if (node.getNextSibling() == null && node.getPreviousSibling() == null) {
        // Node has no siblings
        return false;
    } else {
        // Check if node siblings are of the same name. If so, then we are inside an array.
        return (node.getNextSibling() != null && node.getNextSibling().getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName()))
                || (node.getPreviousSibling() != null && node.getPreviousSibling().getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName()));
    }
}

/**
 *  TODO - doesn't handle Formatted XML - treats formatting as Text Nodes and needs to skip these.
 *  Figures out the Index of the Array Node.
 *
 *  @param node {@link Node}
 *  @return Index of element in array. Returns null if not inside an array.
 */
private Integer getIndexOfArrayNode(Node node) {
    if(isArrayNode(node)) {
        int leftCount = 0;

        Node currentNode = node.getPreviousSibling();

        while(currentNode != null) {
            leftCount++;
            currentNode = currentNode.getPreviousSibling();
        }
        return leftCount;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

outputs would be something like this (potentially):

```
/messages[0]/message/metadata/msg_id
/messages[0]/message/metadata/client_type
/messages[0]/message/individual/name
/messages[1]/message/metadata/msg_id
/messages[1]/message/metadata/client_type
/messages[1]/message/individual/name
etc.
```